# How To Configure WCF Endpoint For a wsdl:port

Tags: wcf, endpoint, wcf-endpoint

```
<wsdl:service name="ExportService">
  <wsdl:port name="ExportServicePort" binding="ExportServicePort">
    <soap12:address location=""/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

<endpoint name="ExportServicePort" ...  contract="....">
  <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

I can change my endpoint configuration so that name and binding are exactly the same, but how can I configure an endpoint so the values are different.

I want something like this:

```
<wsdl:service name="ExportService">
  <wsdl:port name="ExportServiceABC" binding="ExportServiceXYZ">
    <soap12:address location=""/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

What setting do I need in my endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that changing the `name` attribute on the `<endpoint>` element would do the trick, like this:

```
<endpoint name="ExportServiceABC" ... contract="....">
```

You'll also want to change the `name` attribute in your `<binding>` element:

```
<binding name="ExportServiceXYZ" .... >
```

Based on your posted example where the `<endpoint>` name attribute is "ExportServicePort" and that's what shows in the WSDL.